# Calling a non static method in Server Side by a Client Side Function

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, asmx

I can get an object from the server side by using static receive callbackresult methods from server side.

But I want to run a non-static method in my page which populates an ajax accordion by calling a client side function.

The object I am calling from server side is a complex object which I can't use in client side if I get it by callbackresults.

Is there any other solution that I can run a non static method in an aspx file by a client side control ?

Codes I am using so far ...

```
       function ReceiveServerData(arg, context) {
    //Message.innerText = "Date from server: " + arg;
}

#region ICallbackEventHandler Members

public void RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
{
    // Processes a callback event on the server using the event
    // argument from the client.
    Insert(); // this is running, but doesnt work !
    //printAlternativesFromAirport(eventArgument);
}

public string GetCallbackResult()
{
    // Returns the results of a callback event to the client.
return null;
}

#endregion


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScriptManager cm = Page.ClientScript;
    String cbReference = cm.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg",
        "ReceiveServerData", "");
    String callbackScript = "function CallServer(arg, context) {" +
        cbReference + "; }";
    cm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
        "CallServer", callbackScript, true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to  create a handler that will create the entire context needed for the page, which will run a full page life cycle ect, and is more recommended when you want to retrieve something like a user control or something big.

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write(RenderView("~/_controltemplates/15/myDir/Templates/myUC.ascx"));
    }

    public static string RenderView(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            Page pageHolder = new Page();
            UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);
            pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);
            StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
            Log.Application.Debug(LOGPREFIX + "RenderView before Execute");
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, result, true);
            return result.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Application.ErrorException(LOGPREFIX, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

but i think that it is not what you need, instead i would advice you to make an entity (class) to handle that insert function that will not need any httpContext and run it from a simple handler.

another solution you might need, since maybe you do need all the postback info but do not want to make a full postback is to use AjaxPanel or even clear the Response and send "OK" instead.