# Calling an ASP.Net function from javascript

Tags: asp.net, serverside-javascript

Is it possible to call a C# function in my codebehind from javascript?

Comment: You might just use WebServices and AJAX calls...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you call C# function from javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994150/can-you-call-c-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use [PageMethods](http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.all).

Comment: Another link to the PageMethods... http://sappidireddy.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/how-to-call-server-side-function-from-client-side-code-using-pagemethods-in-aspnet-ajax/

Comment: Thanks @Darin. This looks like the way too go. I have one issue though, i'm getting a javascript error stating that PageMethods is not recognised. Could you think of something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot call server-side code
>   ‘directly’ from client-side code. That
>   is because by design, the server side
>   code executes at server side and
>   client side code at the client.
>   However there are some workarounds. To
>   call serverside code from javascript,
>   you will need to use AJAX, and the
>   easiest way out, is to use the ASP.NET
>   AJAX Extensions.

Check this link

[How to call Server Side function from Client Side Code using PageMethods in ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109)

Comment: This is a copy of my answere here ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994150/can-you-call-c-function-from-javascript/3994170#3994170