# Call a c# function from JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pagemethods

i have one function, which is named as `callData()` inside the c#. Now i want to call this function from JavaScript. I don't need any operations on JavaScript. Just i want to call that function. In this problem i don't need any other options.. Just i want to know how to call c# methods from JavaScript.

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function call()
    {
    //To call callData function

    }
</script>
```

Html code

```
 <html>
 <div>
 <asp:Button ID="hbtn" runat="server" OnClientClick="Javascript:call();"/>
 </div>
 </html>
```

C# code

```
public static void callData()
{
 //some operations
}
```

Comment: Show your work and tell us what have you tried so far.. Give people more informations..

Comment: Dupicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994150/can-you-call-c-sharp-function-from-javascript
many many question like this before!

Comment: @AnhTú http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994150/can-you-call-c-sharp-function-from-javascript this url just contains idea.. i need specific coding..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making that C# function a web method with in a web service. Once you do that, you can make use of jQuery and call that function. To my knowledge you cannot just call a C# method within javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decorate your C# server-side method with the `WebMethod` attribute and make it static to expose it as a callable AJAX member:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void callData() {
  //some operations
}
```

Then use the `ajax` method, something like so, in your JavaScript method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "path/to/page/callData",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: {},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) { },
  error: function (xhr, status, error) { }
});
```

Where `successFn`, and `errorFn` are functions to handle successful or failing outcomes respectively, such as.