# Invoking ASP.NET codebehind method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

Can someone please tell me how I can invoke a ASP.NET codebehind method from client-side JavaScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very good article on how to do an Ajax call to a code-behind method: [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 1):

I've always used Page Methods. They are pretty good.

You can read the blogpost by Dave for step by step tutorial: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Use an update panel control is the easiest way, but you can post the page to the server and get the result using Sys.Net.WebRequest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310979.aspx.

That's a lot harder because you have to manually update the response in the page, wipe out the old content, parse the result, and inject the new content.  The typical way it is done is to use a web service and call Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383814.aspx.  This can call a web service within the page (page methods) or a separate ASMX or WCF web service.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) ,
[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/11/07/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods-by-example.aspx) is good source

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "MessagePopup.asmx/SendMessage",
  data: "{subject:'" + subject + "',message:'" + message + ",messageId:'" + messageId + "',pupilId:'" + pupilId +"'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

If you want just using JavaSctipt without using jQuery fallow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript) links