# __doPostBack not working for me

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dopostback

Is there an error in the way i use the __doPostBack?

```
function displaymessage() {
  var scl = "aaaaaa";
  var pageId = '<%=  Page.ClientID %>';
  __doPostBack(pageId, 'OtherInformation');
  alert(scl);
}

<input type="button" value="Click me!" id="Button2" onclick="displaymessage()"   />
```

When i press the button it should call the RaisePostBackEvent in the code file, but it doesn't. If i comment the doPostBack it reaches the alert but when it is uncommented it does not. So it must be an error in the usage of the doPostBack.

I followed this post: [Call ASP.NET function from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript)

Comment: On a side note, any specific reason you want to get this route. Why not use PageMethods (http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/01/08/how-to-move-from-ajaxpro-to-asp-net-ajax-pagemethods.aspx) and related things from Jquery as well?

Comment: Any chance you had the string "alert" in the page's URL?

Answer (score 2):

Place the following script on the header section of your html file:

```
<script>
    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
        document.Form1.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        document.Form1.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        document.Form1.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

for me the _dopostback() was not firing only on IE and chrome browser. I have resolved by adding "return false;" statement in the javascript function. for example:-

```
  function test()
{
    _dopostback("logout","");
return false;
}
```

now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change you code to this:

```
setTimeout(function () { __doPostBack('btnSave', '') }, 500);
```

Use `btnSave Id`. It will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Drop your second argument of `__doPostBack` ('OtherInformation'), and replace with an empty string, `''`. You could put that data in a hidden input field if you need it, and retrieve it using `Request.Form`.

Answer (score 0):

I also followed the same post you mentioned and got an error, I tried to use the other answers here but it still didn't work.

Until I've found this post:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1197643.aspx
(look in the 8th reply made by NC01).

1.basically the idea is that your aspx should have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function myfunction() {

              if ('<%=Page.IsPostBack%>' == 'False') {
                 var pageId = '<%= this.UniqueID %>';
                  __doPostBack(pageId, 'do_something_good');
              }
          }
</script>
```

2.then in your .cs you should add interface IPostBackEventHandler (for example:)

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page, IPostBackEventHandler
```

3.and in your .cs in page_load add this line:

```
this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
```

4.don't forget to implement the interface:

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
  {
   if (eventArgument == "do_something_good")
   {
    //bla
   }
  }
```

And guess what - it even works!

@Subhash Dike - The PageMethods works only for static methods, AFAIK.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add **EnableEventValidation="false"** into your **<%Page** tag to solve __doPostBack problem