# ASP.NET call C# functions from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a small working application in ASP.NET and C#, and I would like to add some JavaScript code to it.

I know that, for example, I can use the <kbd>Confirm</kbd> button and then do something on <kbd>Yes</kbd> or <kbd>No</kbd>.

I would like to call some of the functions I have in the code-behind, depending on the answer to the <kbd>Confirm</kbd> button.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Explain what you **exactly** want, what is are goals and requirements?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.

Put a hidden div on your .aspx page that contains button triggers to your methods:

```html
<div style="display: none">
     <asp:Button ID="TriggerMethod1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

In your JavaScript code, in the confirm part of your code, simply do:

```js
__doPostBack('TriggerMethod1', '');
```

And in your code-behind, handle up that button click to call Method1.

Comment: I personally use jQuery, and just trigger the click with: `$("#TriggerMethod1").click();`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was looking for. Clear and Concise!

Answer (score 1):

I would create an ASHX handler file and post back to the hander using jQuery `ajax` **[methods](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**.

See an article on this here:

[Using jQuery in ASP.NET apps with httphandlers](https://sites.google.com/site/spyderhoodcommunity/tech-stuff/usingjqueryinaspnetappswithhttphandlersashx)

Comment: The second link is broken: *"Site not found"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen FYI: There's [a Wayback Machine save](https://web.archive.org/web/20201019094917/https://sites.google.com/site/spyderhoodcommunity/tech-stuff/usingjqueryinaspnetappswithhttphandlersashx) of that page that works if you want to fix the broken link. Unfortunately, the queue is full, so I can't.

Answer (score 1):

To call a server-side method on a client-side event you need to do the following:

1. Create the server-side method:

   ```
   void DoSomething(...) { ... }
   ```
2. Implement the `System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent` which take one string argument (you can assign the name to the value of this argument).:

   ```
   public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
   {
           DoSomething(...);
   }
   ```
3. Write a script to trigger a post back:

   ```
   function TriggerPostBack(control, arg){
       __doPostBack(control, arg);
   }
   ```
4. Call the PostBack trigger function when needed:

   ```
    <a .... onclick="TriggerPostBack('control', 'arg')" .. />
   ```