# Pass parameters to code behind function using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, inline-code

I'm trying to call a code-behind function inside JavaScript and pass a parameters to the code-behind function.

For example:

```
<script> 
var name; 
<% createUser(name) %> 
</script>

private void createUser(string Name)
{ // Do crazy stuff }
```

I'm doing this because some of the elements are dynamically created using jQuery, so I cannot access them in server side code. The example above is relatively simple and nothing close to what I'm trying to achieve, nevertheless, it does give you a good overview of my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't directly "call" a code-behind function from JavaScript.** JS runs in the client's browser, and C# is running on a server somewhere else. The two communicate using HTTP requests via the medium of a web server. You *can* fire off an HTTP Request from the client, and have a server page waiting to process such requests by delegating to code-behind functions:

- Take a look at [AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479042.aspx).
- [Call ASP.NET function from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript)