# Javascript getElementById gives error 'null' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, null, getelementbyid

I want to call a c# function using javascript, so I added an invisible asp.net button to my Default.aspx, and now I am tring to call it inside javascript so that it will trigger the c# function, but it gives 'null' is null or not an object. I tried to move my javascript part to many places to solve the problem but it didn't work.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server"
ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>

    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <h2>        WELCOME     </h2>
     <div style="display: none;">
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server"
             OnClick="btn_SearchLibrary_Click" />
     </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function displaymessage() {
                var button = document.getElementById('button1');
                button.click();
            }
        </script>


<!-- Some codes in here, below there is a gridview templatefield -->



    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BookName"
    SortExpression="BookName" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1"
    runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BookName") %>'
    NavigateUrl="javascript:displaymessage()"></asp:HyperLink>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Are you sure the rendered page uses the literal `id` format instead of the old `ctl00` prefix format?

Comment: I am not sure, but I am using .NET 4.0, so possibly it will not be an old format, am I right

Comment: JavaScript is on the client. c# is on the server. You cannot "call" a c# function from JavaScript - they're on two different machines!

Comment: Diodeus, please see the second answer that has 18 up votes in this topic, that is what I am tring to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript, I am calling asp.net function with javascript, asp.net function will be firing the c# function

Comment: assuming the javascript error is client-side error in the browser, it will be better to post the markup returned to the browser as well.

Comment: The reasoning is correct, my guess is that .net is adding a subfix to the generated id attibute generating something like `<button id="SoMtHiNg_button1">`, try to see the actual rendered html by right click and see page source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
     document.getElementById('<%=button1.ClientID%>')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should solve this with an Ajax implementation. This way you can call a webservice wich will contain some business logic and sends a response back to the client.

1. Create a web service using eq. (WCF, ServiceStack)
2. Create a button
3. Subscribe to the click event of the button with jQuery and call your webservice.
4. In the success callback function, do some client side logic like updating your list of books.

Best regards,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

While I would highly suggest pursuing an ajax/WCF solution, the problem with your current approach is most likely the ID of the button. ASP controls are usually not rendered with the ID you specify in markup, but prefixed by "ct100" or "container$id" or "container_id", depending on the version of ASP. I would suggest you view source on your page to see the rendered ID and make sure that you are passing that to your document.getElementById.