# call server-side method from javascript in postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, server-side

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call ASP.NET Function From Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript)

In my custom ajax server-side control I draw image (using html5) and I need to invoke server-side function when user click it (just do it usual button).I want to do it like this:

```
    <xx:MyControl ... runat="server" onchange = "server side function"/>
```

I dont want just invoke do_postback function with ControlId an EventArgument parametrs beckause then I must do additional work to specify the action and invoke appopriate function - I want to keep my code-behind clear and I dont want end user that will use my component do this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement IPostBackDataHandler interface, **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx)** and **[this](http://weblogs.asp.net/bhaskarghosh/archive/2008/07/10/custom-control-postback-and-events.aspx)** article will guide you to accomplish this.