# Javascript function to call server side method is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascx

I'm trying to call a server side method in an ascx page through a javascript function. This method worked in an aspx page. It does not seem to call the javascript function but the hidden button does call the server side method.

```
<div runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">

     function WebDatePicker_DayChange(sender, eventArgs)
     {
        document.getElementById("HiddenField3").value = eventArgs.get_value();
        var btn = document.getElementById("Button2");
        btn.click();
    }
 </script></div>


<ig:WebDatePicker runat="server" ID="WebDatePicker1" DropDownCalendarID="webMonthCalendar" DisplayModeFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" EditModeFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" EditMode="CalendarOnly" Nullable="False" AlwaysInEditMode="False" HorizontalAlign ="Center" >                
                    <ClientSideEvents  ValueChanged="WebDatePicker_DayChange" ></ClientSideEvents>             
                </ig:WebDatePicker>

                 <ig:WebMonthCalendar runat="server" ID="webMonthCalendar" Culture="en-us" FooterContent="Today: {0:d}"
                    EnableWeekNumbers="false"
                    ChangeMonthToDateClicked="true" 
                    EnableMonthDropDown="True"  
                    EnableYearDropDown="True">
                </ig:WebMonthCalendar>     
                <input type="button" id="Button2" style="display:none" runat="server"  onserverclick="WebDatePicker_DayChange" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField3" runat="server" Value=""  />
```

Comment: User Control Elements have different ID.. View the page source in browser and check the ID of the Element and try the same...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call ASP.NET Function From Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript)

Comment: The problem is that my js function is not being called at all. this worked in an aspx page but is not working here.

Comment: Pandian solved my question. The control id's were getting changed when the page was loaded. Learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

To trigger that method you need to run the following JavaScript code:

```
__doPostBack('Button2','')
```

Replace `btn.click();` with the code above.

That is an Asp.Net generated method [[docs]](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/)