# how to call server side function from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am looking to set sorting on ASP Repeater. see my repeater code:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptClientDetails">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table id="example" class="dynamicTable table table-striped table-bordered table-primary">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>

                                 <a href="#" onclick="ClientSort('ClientID')">Client ID</a>


                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                     <a href="#" onclick="ClientSort('Name')">Name</a>


                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                     <a href="#" onclick="ClientSort('TotalBalanceDue')">Total Balance Due</a>


                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
```

here, i am calling javascript function. see my javascript function code:

```
function ClientSort(SortExpress) {

           <%= Sorting(SortExpress) %>
         }
```

from here i want to call my .net server side function.

```
public void Sorting(string SortExpression)
{
    string s = SortExpression;

}
```

so, have you idea how can i call it? or directly from repeater i can call this server side function..Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly you can call server side code from repeater control, just use Linkbutton instead of href.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptClientDetails">
   <HeaderTemplate>
            <table id="example" class="dynamicTable table table-striped table-bordered table-primary">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <%--<a href="#" onclick="ClientSort('ClientID')">Client ID</a>--%>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn" Text="Client ID" ForeColor="Blue" OnCommand="lbtnSorting_Click" CommandArgument="ClientID" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Name" ForeColor="Blue" OnCommand="lbtnSorting_Click" CommandArgument="Name" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                            <%--<a href="#" onclick="ClientSort('Name')">Name</a>--%>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Text="Total Balance Due" ForeColor="Blue" OnCommand="lbtnSorting_Click" CommandArgument="TotalBalanceDue" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                            <%--<a href="#" onclick="ClientSort('TotalBalanceDue')">Total Balance Due</a>--%>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And the Code Behind :

```
protected void lbtnSorting_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply call an `ASP.NET`-method from your JavaScript. This is because ASP.NET is purely server-side and JavaScript is client-side.
ASP.NET generates HTML and JavaScript from your .NET code and this happens ONLY during postbacks or Initial loads.
ASP.NET renders a side, provides it and from this Moment on is out of the game until postback.

See [ASP.NET-page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript) post.

Answer (score 1):

To invoke server-side code without reloading the page, use jquery ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i have no consult with load page...i just want to call server side function from javascript...

Comment: and this is how you can do it

Comment: if you have difficulties implementing ajax communication between client and server, you can ask specific questions

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue got fixed by following code...hope someone will benefit:-
I need to call a server side function (button click event functionality) from client side just by Onblur of a Textbox:

asp:TextBox ID="txtNum" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox"  Width="170px" MaxLength="8" onblur="javascript:return check2();"/>"

```
 //JAVASCRIPT - onblur calls button click serverside function
 function check2() {
     document.getElementById("<%=btncheck.ClientID%>").click(); 
 }
```

asp:Button ID="btncheck" runat="server" Text="Verify" OnClick="check1" />

```
//CODE BEHIND - On clicking the Button
protected void check1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str1 = txtBox.Text;
    CheckCCN2(str1);        
}
//Onblur of the Textbox txtNum   
public void CheckCCN2(string strCCNNum)
{
  //all your server side code    
}
```