# Add javascript event to input checkbox to execute in codebehind asp.net,

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events

I have a html control in aspx page.

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="Booking" id="chkBooking" class="css-checkbox" runat="server" /><label for="chkBooking" class="css-label">Booking</label>
```

I would like to add a javascript event when checkbox is clicked, and that event to be executed in codebehind, like this example here I found on the web:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", displayControlName + 
    ".innerText=this.value.length;");
```

How can I call that event also in the code behind?

Comment: The code behind the aspx page

Comment: Still not clear, what should be the expected outcome when the user checks/un-checks the ``checkbox``?

Comment: When the user clicks the html checkbox i want a method to be executed in the code behind of the aspx page.

Comment: in html control " runat="server" ", what is this for.

Comment: i put that so i can see the control in code behind in aspx page.

Comment: Many solutions already there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441194/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript
--
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828803/how-to-call-code-behind-server-method-from-a-client-side-javascript-function

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand this question. You can set AutoPostback="true" on an asp.net Checkbox and set its onCheckedChanged event.

```
<asp:CheckBox id="cb" OnCheckedChanged="cb_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
```

and, in the code behind

```
protected void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//do whatever you want
}
```

alertnatively, you can wire up a javascript event to click a button if you want - but why do that when it already has the ability to do a postback?

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="submitit()">
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" Height="0" Width="0" CssClass="hidden" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitit()
{
document.getElementById('btn').click();
}
```

Then, when the checkbox is clicked, the javascript function clicks the button, the page postbacks and btn_Click runs.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: yes, but i want to use a html control because in the html control ican apply css, not in the asp checkbox

Comment: @user3816931, you can apply css in asp controls too. Try using "CssClass" attribute.

Comment: its not working , is there a way to just trigger a codebehind event for the html input checkbox?

Comment: You can definitely apply CSS attributes to an asp checkbox as said above using the CssClass attribute. If it is a html checkbox why don't you run a javascript function to submit a hidden button? I am editing my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript on checked event

```
if(chkBooking.Checked)
{
    String scriptText = String.Empty;
    scriptText += "function ShowAlert(){";
    scriptText += "  alert( " + 
        " document.forms[0].TextBox1.value";
    scriptText += ")}";

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
       "CounterScript", scriptText, true);
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i just want a codebehind asp.net event method to be called when the input checbox is clicked.

Comment: @user3816931 : then why you tag this question in js

Answer (score 0):

Create an asp:HiddenField (in this case ID is hiddenField) and fetch the checkbox value using the jQuery code below:

It works for me. you can view more from this question [question][Get checkbox value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834350/get-checkbox-value-in-jquery)

```
$('#chkBooking').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();            
        $('#hiddenField').val($('#chkBooking').val());
    $("form").submit();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to call a server side function on Button click then why not going for a server side button control and call your desired function when button's OnClick event fires.

**YourPage.aspx**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="BigButton" OnClick="BigButton_Click" Text="Big Button" />
```

**YourPage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void BigButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Call your function from here
    }
```

**Note :** *You can add css on server side controls using CssClass attributes.*

```
<asp:Label CssClass="bingo" ID="displayLabel" runat="server" />
```

Or try this answer :

[How to call a C# function from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441194/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript)