# Calling C# Code Behind from Javascript using PageMethods doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods

I'm trying to call my C# Web method from my javascript on 'Enter key press' using PageMethods.

ASP:

```
<input id="new-chat-text-input" type="text" placeholder="Your Message Here..." onkeydown="chatreply(event)">
```

Javascript:

```
function chatreply() {
  var inputtext = document.getElementById("new-chat-text-input");
  var x = event.keyCode;
  if (x == 13) {
      alert("The process came here"); //Gets triggered successfully
      var chatresult= PageMethods.SendChat(inputtext)
      alert(chatresult);
  }
}
```

Code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SendChat(string input)
{
      return "Hey there";
}
```

Basically trying to get the input text from a textbox, send it to a method in the code behind and alert the response. I basically get an empty alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441194/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/631342/Calling-csharp-function-in-javascript

Comment: @mason This question demonstrates what this site has become. Everyone is quick to downvote what they don't understand.

Comment: @Eterm sigh, they don't even attempt to clarify a question anymore..

Comment: @Eterm What are you talking about? That has nothing to do with the question, and a single downvote on a question doesn't really mean a whole lot. And lastly, why are you directing your comment at me?

Comment: http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2

Comment: I suggest you edit your title, post, and tags to indicate that this question is specifically about PageMethods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with [PageMethods](http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2), but from what I can see on a quick read, it returns immediately while performing an asynchronous AJAX call in the background.  You must provide a callback for success and error.  The success handler should display the result.

```
function aichatreply() {
    var inputtext = document.getElementById("new-chat-text-input");
    var x = event.keyCode;
    if (x == 13) {
        alert("The process came here"); //Gets triggered successfully
        PageMethods.SendChat(inputtext, onSuccess, onFailure);
        //This line will execute immediately, not waiting for SendChat to finish
    }
}

function onSuccess(result) {
    alert(result);
}

function onFailure(result) {
    alert("Failed!");
}
```

Comment: Cool, too bad this question was closed!  I don't think anybody really read it very carefully.

Comment: Indeed! People are too quick to move on haha. Thanks man!