# Call C# functions in Javascript for Acumatica

Tags: javascript, c#, acumatica

How to call `C#` function in `Javascript` with  Acumatica platform?
I tried  `alert( '<% = ScanPageCount%>')` does not work

Comment: do you look here [How to call a C# function from javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441194/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript)

Comment: I dont utilize `static` method this is my function  
       `public string ScanPageCount()`
       `{`
           `return  this.MyPanel.Current.PageCount.ToString();`
        `}`

Comment: @SinanBARAN link doesn't apply for Acumatica