# calling a c# class method from html page

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Can we call a C# method in a class from a html page??
I have a class names Crud.cs

```
public class Crud
{
    public String generateFiles(String name)
    {

        return(generateHtml(name));
    }
     private String generateHtml(String name)
    {

       var filename = "C:\temp\"" + name + ".html";

        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            return "True";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to call this method from a html page.I'm using a html page not a asp page.Is there any possibility to call without using ajax or if ajax also how could I call.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     

</head>
<body>
    <div style="align-content:center;">
        <input type="text" id="HtmlName" />
        <button id="btn_gen_html" onclick="createHtml()">Generate</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Msg"></div> 
    <div id="feedbackMsg"></div> 
    <script>
        function createHtml() {
            var name = document.getElementById("HtmlName").value;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Crud.cs/generateFiles",
                data: { name } ,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (val) {
                    alert(val);

                    if (val == 0) {
                        $("#feedbackMsg").html("Success");
                    }
                    else(val==1)
                    {
                        $("#feedbackMsg").html("Sorry cannot perform such operation");
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $("#feedbackMsg").html("Something Wrong.");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. Here I am not able to call generateFiles() method in crud class. Can I call so.And if I can How?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. `Crud.cs/generateFiles` is an invalid URL in AJAX call (since .cs files are compiled & you need to return HTML/JSON), even C# code doesn't reached. If you're using ASP.NET MVC, the URL assigned with controller & action method name (set the action method to return JSON result).

Comment: Hi  @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks for fast reply.. But I didn't get what u telling. Can u please explain in brief

Comment: Try something like this ProjectName.namespace.c#function. you can't call .cs file like that

Comment: @MeghaM use change the method to static and put [WebMethod].

Comment: The AJAX call URL requires valid routing to interact with C# code, so that you can't use .cs files directly. In ASP.NET MVC the URL routing is enabled, so that you can use controller class name & action method name to refer in URL. However with setup you have above without any URL routing, the AJAX doesn't know which route should be taken to call backend C# code.

Comment: You can refer to this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441194/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can't call normal method. The method must be static and web method.

Try this:

```
public class Crud
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static String generateFiles(String name)
    {

        return(generateHtml(name));
    }
     private String generateHtml(String name)
    {

       var filename = "C:\temp\"" + name + ".html";

        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            return "True";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax

```
<script type="text/javascript">             //Default.aspx
   function myfunction() {     
             $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'Default.aspx/myfunction',
             data: "mystring",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (msg) {
                 alert("success");
             },
             error: function (e) {
                 $("#divResult").html("Something Wrong.");
             }
         });
     }
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public static String myfunction(string name)
{
    return "Your String"
}
```

If you want to use page call without ajax: [Ref](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2008/10/04/aspnet-ajax-pagemethods/)

```
//cs file (code behind)
[ScriptMethod, WebMethod]
public static string GetLabelText(string param1)
{
   return "Hello";
}
//aspx page
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function InsertLabelData() {
      PageMethods.GetLabelText(param1,onSuccess, onFailure);
  }

  function onSuccess(result) {
      var lbl = document.getElementById(‘lbl’);
      lbl.innerHTML = result;
  }

  function onFailure(error) {
      alert(error);
  }
  InsertLabelData();
</script>
```

Comment: How to send parameters in second method PageMethods.GetLabelText(onSuccess, onFailure);

Comment: @MeghaM have you tested?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a controler in your project.

You try to retrieve data from a cs file without a controler (or a [WebMethod])? this is impossible.

Try looking for some MVC guides, Here is one [from microsoft web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller)

You dont have to use all that ASP component that showen there, but you can see there how to retrieve data from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET Web Forms, there is a `WebMethodAttribute` you can use instead of calling `.cs` file directly which unsupported by AJAX due to no URL routing enabled for normal classes. The web method [must be declared as `static`](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx):

```
// if you're using ASMX web service, change to this class declaration:
// public class Crud : System.Web.Services.WebService
public class Crud : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static String generateFiles(String name)
    {
        return generateHtml(name);
    }

    private String generateHtml(String name)
    {
        var filename = "C:\temp\"" + name + ".html";

        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            return "True";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your AJAX call URL should be changed to this (note that the web method should be exist in code-behind file, e.g. `Crud.aspx.cs` or `Crud.asmx.cs`):

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Crud.aspx/generateFiles", // web service uses .asmx instead of .aspx
          data: { name: name }, // use JSON.stringify if you're not sure
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (val) {
             alert(val);
             if (val == 0) {
                $("#feedbackMsg").html("Success");
             }
             else
             {
                 $("#feedbackMsg").html("Sorry cannot perform such operation");
             }
          },
          error: function (e) {
             $("#feedbackMsg").html("Something Wrong.");
          }
});
```

If ASP.NET MVC is used, use `JsonResult` to return JSON string as `success` result:

```
public class CrudController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult generateFiles(String name)
    {
        return Json(generateHtml(name));
    }
}
```

The AJAX call for the action method looks similar but the URL part is slightly different:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Crud/generateFiles",
          data: { name: name }, // use JSON.stringify if you're not sure
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (val) {
             alert(val);
             if (val == 0) {
                $("#feedbackMsg").html("Success");
             }
             else
             {
                 $("#feedbackMsg").html("Sorry cannot perform such operation");
             }
          },
          error: function (e) {
             $("#feedbackMsg").html("Something Wrong.");
          }
});
```

Comment: But I'm using just a class not .aspx.cs file ..So how can I give it in url..My file name is Crud.cs..How can I use it in url

Comment: To use `WebMethod`, the method should placed in a class that derives `System.Web.UI`. So that you can create `Crud.aspx` page & `Crud.aspx.cs` code behind, then you can use web method inside `public class Crud : System.Web.UI.Page`. If you're taking MVC route, just adding `Controller` to make it controller class & decorate action method with `HttpPost`.

Comment: But I'm not using .aspx page..I'm just  using .html page  I'm not using MVC, I'm using webforms

Comment: You can call the C# code from web method URL with just HTML & JS, but the C# code takes place inside code-behind file, either in ASPX or ASMX web service (.asmx.cs) code which has `WebMethod` (`public class Crud : WebService`).

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Perfect solution
  var params = { param1: value, param2: value2}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: '../aspxPage.aspx/methodName',
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
       var  MethodReturnValue = data.d

        },
        error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
            alert(" conection to the server failed ");
        }
    });
```

//PLEASE menntion [WebMethod] attribute on your method.