# How to pass data to Javascript from Code Behind in C#.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this issue calendar project that I am working with. It has a `javascript` running to add events. I wanted to get those events and save it in `MS SQL`. However I have no Idea. If i can get the `javascript` events to `C#` code behind I can save it. If you can help me get the `javascript` data to `C#.net` or if you can help me to directly save `javascript` to `MS SQL` that would be helpful. Here is part of the `javascript` intended to create event on a calendar.

```
   select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                bootbox.prompt("New Event Title:", function (title) {
                    if (title !== null) {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                            {
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end,
                                allDay: allDay,
                                className: 'label-info'
                            },
                            true 
                        );
                    }
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between `Client` side and `Server`. Database usually exists on `Server` side, so you can't save directly to your DB from `JavaScript` code.

Comment: You can't pass data from `C#` to `JavaScript` ,but you can pass data from `Client` to `Server`.

Comment: Thanks on that. can you give me an Idea on how I can call the variables of this js to my code behind so that I can store it DB. Thanks.

Comment: Mr. Feras, can you enlighten me on that? Thanks.

Comment: I pass the data from C# to this: events: [ <%=CalendarData%> ]

I use the public string of C#.net CalendarData which gets data from MS SQL. However, I wanted to store the data from js to MS SQL now. I am having hard time.

Comment: @KishRosa You can show this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming) to know how implement that.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks So much. I saw this example. Instead I will call a function in C#.net from JS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441194/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript

Comment: Certainly you can use `jQuery.ajax()` method, ensure that the data submitted in proper format. The URL part should point to the ASPX page which accepts either query string argument or postback argument.

Answer (score 0):

One of the few and best ways is using a hidden field like this:

- In aspx code:

  ```
  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
  ```
- In code behind set it's value:

  ```
  HiddenField1.Value = Value
  ```
- In javascript you can access it like this:

  ```
  document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value
  ```

  OR the other way around if you want to send from Js to C#:
- in javascript:

  ```
  document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value=Value
  ```
- In code behind:

  ```
  a=HiddenField1.Value
  ```