# how can I combine code behind and javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have function in javascript (in client side) `alertmemedium()` that call to an alert, which the client shpuld choose one option of two.
And I need that if he will click the OK button, The function `RegisterUser()` (from code behind) will run, if the client will click the seconed button nothing will happened.
So even if I call `RegisterUser()` in `alertmemedium()` -- (like that <%RegisterUser();%>) -- in if condition the function from code behind ignore everything and just run by itself before it called. RegisterUser() written in code behind c#.

the js function:

```
function alertmemedium(){
        const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
          customClass: {
            confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
            cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
          },
          buttonsStyling: false
        })

        swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
          title: 'Are you sure?',
          text: "Your Password has a medium strength!",
          type: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes!',
          cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
          reverseButtons: true
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
              'Well done!',
              'You signed up to our website.',
              'success'
              )
```

this is the call to the cade behind function -- continue -->

```
              <%RegisterUser();%>
          } else if (
            result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
          ) {
            swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
              'Cancelled',
              'Improve Your Password!:)',
              'error'
              )
                          }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach is to call an API instead method.
You may try the accepted answer from this query:

[How to call a C# function from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441194/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript)

Another approach is to have a blank text button and fire that using click by javascript:

```
//make a button:
<asp:Button ID="DummyButton" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="RegisterUser"  />

//fire follwing by replacing <%RegisterUser();%>
document.getElementById('<%= DummyButton.ClientID %>').click();
```