# Calling a C# function from JavaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to call a c# function from JavaScript. I tried the solution specified in [Call ASP.NET function from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript) but the `RaisePostBackEvent` is not getting called.

My JavaScript is:

```
<script>
    function link_load() {
        var pageId = '<%=  Page.ClientID %>';
        __doPostBack(pageId, argumentString);
        document.getElementById("sidebar1").innerHTML = "working";
    }
</script>
```

My C# code is:

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    sidebar1.InnerHtml = "working inside";
}
```

The JavaScript code is executed, which I verified.

Comment: Have you tried changing a hidden field's value from javascript and postback, then check the hidden value in c#'s pageload function ?

Comment: Are you inherit "IPostBackEventHandler" interface in you page ?

Comment: tackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript

Comment: @EmreAcar Can you explain, please ? I do not understand what you suppose.

Comment: do you have an event handler assigned that references the RaisePostBackEvent method?

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ  I have added the link in my question. I'm not able to call the function still.

Comment: @ps2goat I haven't. Can you please explain further ?

Comment: never mind.  It may have to do with the order of eventing.  When you post back with web forms, the entire lifecycle executes.  The assignment you are doing (`sidebar1.InnerHtml = "working inside"`) happens early in the cycle.  In the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.raisepostbackevent.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2, they are raising the click event so the code actually executes when it should, which is after Page_Load.  You should perhaps ensure the code is executing in the expected order and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

```
[webmethod]
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    sidebar1.InnerHtml = "working inside";
}
```

in javascriptenter code here

```
<script type="javascript">
 $.ajax({
     url:'pagename.aspx/RaisePostBackEvent'`enter code here`
      enter code here

  });
</script>
```