# How to call function in code-behind c# with javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind

How to call function in code-behind in c# with javascript?

I have this code behind :

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btn != null && btn.Checked)
    {
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("get.aspx?a={0}&b={1}", 
                                         a.SelectedValue, b.SelectedValue));
    }
}
```

And I have a Checkbox :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="btn" runat="server" Checked="false" />
```

I am tryong to call that function btn_Click in javascript :

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

if (btn.checked) {
    '<% = btn_Click() %>'
}
```

But not worked!!! Why? 
Thanks.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript

Comment: try this document.getElementById('<%=btn.ClientID %>') and see if that works.Also alert(btn) and see if its not returning null. Also you need to do postback to call server side btn_click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a proper ajax approach explained here -> http://www.techillumination.in/2013/07/an-aspnet-way-to-call-server-side.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this using Jquery, This is not tested

```
var button = $("#btn");
$(button).trigger("click");
```

Comment: Not worked:         `var btn = $("#btn");
        if (btn.checked) {
            $(btnV).trigger("btn_Click()");
        }`

Comment: did u added jquery library it is jquery and is supposed to work

Comment: in my aspx page: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>` and the `btn_Click` not called ...