# Can I access C# Objects alongside from ChakraCore?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am new to `C#` and `ChakraCore`, and I wonder whether it is likely to access `C#` classes from `JavaScript` in `ChakraCore`. For example, I got a `Person` class below:

```
public  class People
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to run a JavaScript file named "test.js" shown as below:`

```
 var person = new People();
```

I have already figured out how to call native `JavaScript` function from `C#` and how `C#` can set some basic variables to `JavaScript`, here comes the question: Can I access `C#` references from `JavaScript`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825558/how-to-access-c-sharp-class-from-javascript